# TIdTCPServer OnExecute event send stream to browser

Tags: delphi, indy, tcpserver

I'm having problems with sending a stream to the client internet browser when he types the host and port my TCPServer listens to. When I type :

```
AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write(clientResponseStream);
```

in my TCPServer OnExecute event the only way to send the information to the client's browser is If I make my server inactive.

```
TCPServer.Active := False
```

-> only after this there is some information in his browser. And it is not the whole data - some pictures are there, some are missing. Can someone help me how to send my (whole) data without having to disconnect my server ?

For every GET request (in my OnExecute event) I have HTTP response that my TCPClient receives with

```
TCPClient.IOHandler.ReadStream(cStream, cStream.Size, False);
```

that lookes kinda like this :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.4.7
Date: Thu, 08 May 2014 18:46:43 GMT
Content-Type: application/x-javascript
Last-Modified: Fri, 28 Mar 2014 09:54:42 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Expires: Thu, 31 Dec 2037 23:55:55 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=315360000
1a89
// some jquery here ...
```

and I send this data with

```
AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write(cStream);
```

Comment: Why are you using `TIdTCPServer` directly and not `TIdHTTPServer`?  Does the content of your stream consist of a **complete** HTTP response, including HTTP headers? Or are you sending them separately?  Deactivating the server DOES NOT trigger data to be sent. What it does do is trigger a socket disconnect. So what is most likely the case is that your HTTP response in not complete, and the browser is waiting for data that you are not sending, and then it stops waiting when the socket is closed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau , Yes - the content of my stream consists of a valid and complete HTTP response and I'm using TIdTCPServer because I should be able to connect to mysql service (and other services that require TCP connectivity) with TIdTCPServer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau In my OnExecute event I have TIdTCPClient that in some cases has to connect to mysql service and then I have to send what it received via my TIdTCPServer to the client's browser.

Comment: Obviously your stream is NOT a complete HTTP response, or else the browser would not be waiting for the data.  Please show the actual content of the stream. Also, you can connect to your SQL database in the `TIdHTTPServer.OnCommand...` events, and then use the `AResponseInfo.Content...` properties to send data back to the browser as needed, letting `TIdHTTPServer` handle the HTTP framing for you.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - I edited the question for more details.

Comment: You are not providing a `Content-Length` header in your response, but you are providing a `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header.  Are you sending a blank line after the headers? Are you sending properly formatted chunks, with a proper 0-length chunk at the end? My guess is no, which would explain why the browser is waiting for data. Read RFC 2616 sections [4.4 Message Length](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-4.4) and [3.6.1 Chunked Transfer Coding](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-3.6.1) for more details.

Comment: And why is your client using `TIdTCPClient` instead of `TIdHTTP`? You appear to have a lot to learn about the HTTP protocol in general, and about Indy's built-in support for HTTP in particular (since you are not utilizing any of it).

Comment: Thanks again, Remy. And you're right - I haven't thought about using TIdHTTP - it will certainly collect the response I need :)